# Determine that a database is currently mirroring or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, mirroring

Is there a T-SQL script to determine a database is currently mirroring or not? Is there a way to determine its partner?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system view / catalog sys.database_mirroring gives a comphrehensive breakdown of the fields available. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655.aspx

Comment: great! I'm reading it. Thank you.
EDIT: solve my problem completely. Thank you, again :D